# Adding extended properties to a not-yet-created Google Calendar event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I'm writing a Google Calendar add-on that needs to be able to add [extended properties](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/extended-properties) to a calendar event **before** it's actually created. This happens when you open the add-on in the Calendar UI and then click in the calendar view to create a new event:

[image: Creating a new event in Google Calendar]

The [`eventOpenTrigger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#eventopentrigger) calls `onEventOpen` when this event is opened:

```js
// main.gs

function onEventOpen(e) {
  const calId = e.calendar.calendarId;
  const calEventId = e.calendar.id;
  // Surprisingly, `e.calendar.id` *always* looks like a valid ID,
  // even though `Calendar.Events.get` throws a 404 Not Found error.
  const calEvent = Calendar.Events.get(calId, calEventId);
  // `Calendar.Events.get` throws a 404 Not Found error when
  // the event is opened as in the above screenshot. It does *not*
  // throw when an *existing* event is opened and edited.
  Calendar.Events.patch({
    extendedProperties: {
      private: { hello: 'world' },
    },
  }, calId, calEventId);
  // ... return a card ...
}
```

I considered creating a "Calendar updated" trigger, but its handler would not be able to return a card to show in the add-on UI, which is needed for this add-on. Is this something that is possible? Or is there an alternative strategy to adding extended properties to a Calendar event before it's created?

Comment: It is not possible to add [extended properties](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/extended-properties) to a calendar event **before** it is created, nor is it possible to create "default" extended properties or something similar. However, there is no need to set your existing properties in an ```Event.patch``` call, you can also set them in a regular ```Event.insert``` call when you are creating the event.

Comment: @OriolCastander So you are saying that within the same insert event call, we can include extendedProperties as part of that new event? I'm not sure why my extendedProperties are not showing up when I create a new Event and pass it through the Google Calendar API